Compatibility Issue: Appium Integration with Selenium WebDriver 4.18.1 for iOS Testing on Browserstack App Automate
I'm working on automation using NUnit framework alongside Selenium WebDriver version 4.18.1. My goal is to execute these test scripts on iPad and iPhone devices using Browserstack App Automate. Unfortunately, due to project constraints, downgrading the Selenium WebDriver version is not an option.
I've attempted to integrate Appium WebDriver versions 5.0.0-alpha, 5.0.0-beta4, and 5.0.0-rc.7 with the mentioned Selenium version. However, upon triggering the iOS driver, I encounter the following error: "Error: Platform can be one of MAC, WIN8, XP, WINDOWS, and ANY". Despite passing the supported platformName, the iOSDriver consistently replaces it with "iOS" every time it is called.
Lower versions of Appium seem to have compatibility issues with the specified version of Selenium WebDriver. I conducted a trial run with Appium WebDriver 4.4.0 and Selenium WebDriver 3.141.0, and the test scripts functioned seamlessly on Browserstack App Automate. However, reverting to an older version of Selenium WebDriver is not feasible for our project.
Is there a compatible version of Appium that works with Selenium WebDriver 4.18.1, or are there alternative solutions to Appium that I could explore?


Could you please check whether "app" capability is added?


@AshwinPathak I'm attempting to initiate a website launch on an iPhone/iPad device. I've supplied the URI during the initialization of the iOSDriver.
